# Database structure to allow users to vote on a topic

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a **Job** model and a **User** model. I need each **User** to be able to answer several questions based on a particular **Job**. Each question is marked from 1 to 10 (or unanswered).

I believe i need a [`hasMany through`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1650/hasMany-through-The-Join-Model) associations, but have been confused by these before.

Can someone help me with my database/model layout. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

- The only tables I have at the moment are users and jobs
- The questions are the same for every job, there are six of them (maybe more in the future)
- The Questions will always be numbers from 1 to 10 (or unanswered)

Comment: where do you keep your Questions? Are they in the Job table?

Comment: If the number of questions might increase in the future, then you should consider putting them in a separate table.

Comment: If the only tables you have right now are Users and Jobs, then where do you keep your questions? Are they in the Jobs table, or just in the html/php of the pages? And where do you keep the answer values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, perfect candidat for hasMany through, and I'll do it like so:

```
User hasMay JobQuestion
Job hasMany JobQuestion

JobQuestion belongsTo Job, User
```

put all your questions in the JobQuestion model. There might be a more appropriate name for this model. Do you need more details for the models keys?

Edit:

A row in the JobQuestion model would:

id | user_id | job_id | question1 | ... | questionN

Your data array would something like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [JobQuestion] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [job_id] => 1
                    [question1] => answer1
                    [question2] => answer2
                )

            [Job] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => somejob
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [username] => someuser
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a row in JobQuestion please?

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be:

Tables: User, Job, Question, Answer

- **Job** hasMany **Questions**
- **User** hasMany **Answers**
- **Question** hasMany **Answers**

Your **Answer** table could have the following columns: user_id, question_id, answer(NULL or 1-10)

You don't need a **Question** table if it's integrated into **Job** somehow.

**EDIT:** Updated to remove redundant **id** from Answer table as per comment suggestion.

Comment: Normalize that Answer table some more and you then remove the ID-field since a User should only be able to answer a question once? Because in that case id would just be redundant.

Comment: @Tobias point taken. It would be easier to normalize if I knew more about the existing tables though.

Comment: You might possibly also want to distinguish between answers and responses. It's hard to know from the original post whether the possible answers to the questions will always only ever be a number from 1 to 10. If not (i.e. if there could be multiple choices or text answers etc), then you might want to look at separate tables for the answers (i.e. all possible answers per question) and responses (the chosen answer to a question by a user).

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your model properly, it sounds like users select jobs, and then answer questions specific to that job (some of which may apply to more than one job)? if so I'm thinking your table structure should look something like this:

First there are your discrete entities.

```
Users:
    UserID (PK)
    User

Jobs:
    JobID (PK)
    JobName
```

Note that if some of the questions are general in nature and apply to more than one Job, then Questions should be defined as follows:

```
Questions
    QuestionID (PK)
    Question
```

Otherwise, if each question is specific to a particular Job, your COULD avoid at least one association table and incorporate an FK to Jobs into the questions table:

```
Questions
    QuestionID
    JobID
    Question
```

But I don't recommend this unless you are certain that Questions are inique to each job.

Next, your associations:

```
User_Jobs (Composite key = FK on USerID, FK on JobID)
    UserID 
    JobID

Job_Questions (Composite Key = FK on JobID, FK on QuestionID)
    JobID
    QuestionID

User_Job_Questions (this one would contain a feild for responses, and could also be named User_Response)
    UserID
    JobID
    QuestionID
    Response (likley constrained to ints from 1-10)
```

Note that User_Job_Questions would contain a composite FK on JobID and QuestionID relating back to Job_Questions and another FK back to Users.

Comment: I have updated my question, mainly regarding: "The questions are the same for every job, there are six of them (maybe more in the future)"

Answer (score 0):

Job hasAndBelongsToMany Question as the same question can apply to multiple jobs.

However to implement your answers you use this approach, a [HasManyThoughJoin](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1650/hasMany-through-The-Join-Model) . In The JobQuestion table you could store the answer AND the user_id.